# convert angular-cli project to angular project? (with no cli)

Tags: angularjs

Is there a way I can turn my existing angular-cli into an angular project(with no cli)?
I want to do try something in my app, I get cros problem when i try to use form authentication even my server allow cors. so I don't want to use localhost 4200.

Comment: You're making two questions here, one related to migrate your project and the other is about your problems with CORS on Authentication

Answer (score 0):

If you are using

Angular 1 : you can convert by adding all dependencies file paths in the index.html

Angular 2 : You should use transpiler(like babel ..) to convert your typescript  code to javascript code and give those java script file  paths in the index.html to work.(recommended to use angular-cli)

If you are facing CORS issue, for development workaround you can add CORS plugin to the chrome